# Getting exception when using foreach but regular for loop executes well

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, foreach

Using regular foloop, getting correct output, using for each loop throws ArrayOutOfBound exception. Can anyone explain?

```
public class FindTheDiff {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(isAnagramRecursion("all","laa"));
}

private static boolean isAnagramRecursion(String param1, String param2) {
    int[] arr = new int[122];
    char[] param1Lower = param1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] param2Low2 = param2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    for (char ch1 : param1Lower) {
        arr[ch1] = arr[ch1]+1;
    }

    for (char ch2 : param2Low2){
        arr[ch2] = arr[ch2]-1;
    }

    for (int i :arr) {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
            return false;
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
            return false;
    }*/
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `i` is **not the index** of the array, it's the **value** of the array. But in the regular loop `i` is the index.

```
for (int i :arr) {
    if(arr[i] != 0)
       return false;
}
```

Use the value of the array means `i` in if condition

```
for (int i :arr) {
    if(i != 0)
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong loop. When doing a forEach loop, you iterate over the value, not the index. The correct forEach loop in your case should be:

```
for (int arrValue :arr) {
    if(arrValue != 0)
        return false;
}
```